# Wrong page opening in localhost

Tags: wamp

I just uploaded a c99shell.php file into my WWW folder in WAMP server. Now even after I delete the file, when I go to localhost, a page is shown which was the index page when c99shell.php was present in the folder, which is different from the one which is currently on my WWW dir. Now if I make a folder inside the WWW directory and then create new files then when I go to localhost/(folder_name) I get the correct files.. Whats more interesting is that, when I delete all the files from the WWW directory, when I go to localhost the old page is shown which was the index page when the c99shell.php page was there.. Please Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

index.* is the default page to show, when no particular is chosen e.g. the address http://localhost/ will lead you to index.html, or index.php if available.

The browser also caches the pages for more speed. So when you've deleted the page, it is still in the browser's cache. To refresh and prevent the pulling the page from cache press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

just clear your cache and you will have everything correct.